# Crontab run only a part of the script

Tags: python, bash, cron

My script **test.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

source activate rsgislib_dev

/home/user/anaconda2/envs/rsgislib_dev/bin/python /opt/AGR/resample.py

/home/user/anaconda2/envs/rsgislib_dev/bin/python /opt/AGR/stack_bands.py


us_1=$(/home/user/anaconda2/envs/rsgislib_dev/bin/python <(cat << 'EOF'
import sys;
import glob;

us_T34TCP = glob.glob('/tmp/sen/stack_bands/*T34TCP*.kea')
us_T34TCP_L_to_str = ''.join(us_T34TCP)
print us_T34TCP_L_to_str

EOF
))
echo $us_1


is_1="${us_1:0:71}3${us_1:72}"
echo $is_1

gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:32633 $us_1 $is_1 -r cubic -tr 10 10 -of KEA

rm $us_1

source deactivate
```

**Cron**

```
30 12 * * * /opt/AGR/test.sh
```

The script works manually, but crontab executes only part. Execute the python script and then it stops.

Does anyone have an idea what the problem is?

Comment: Create Log and error files for your script, to debug why is it not executing further like this, `30 12 * * * /opt/AGR/test.sh 1>/opt/AGR/test.log 2>/opt/AGR/test.err`

Comment: I made logs. The problem is that it does not activate the source (`source activate rsgislib_dev`). log --> `/opt/AGR/test.sh: line 50: activate: No such file or directory.` Any idea?

Comment: When I manually execute a script, everything is ok. When I run over crontab does not activate the `source`.

Comment: `source` searches the directories in `PATH` variable.  Make sure it is set properly so that your `activate` script can be found by the script when cron runs it.

Answer (score 0):

Im solved.

```
....
cd /home/user/anaconda2/envs/rsgislib_dev/bin
source activate rsgislib_dev
...
```